# Adding Advanced Search in ASP.NET MVC 3 / .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, t-sql, lucene.net

In a website I am working on, there is an advanced search form with several fields, some of them dynamic that show up / hide depending on what is being selected on the search form.

Data expected to be big in the database and records are spread over several tables in a very normalized fashion.

Is there a recommendation on using a 3rd part search engine, sql server full text search, lucene.net, etc ... other than using SELECT / JOIN queries?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thinking a little outside the box here -

Check out [CSLA.NET](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/); Using this framework you can create business objects and "denormalise" your search algorithm.

Either way, be sure the database has proper indexes in place for better performance.

Comment: proper indexes I've put based on the key-combination that could be used in a "Where" clause, correct?

Comment: yes, and on join columns in tables as well. you can use the SQL database engine tuning advisor to help find out what to create for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

On the frontend youre going to need to use some javascript to map which top level fields show sub level fields.  Its pretty straight forward.

For the actual search, I would recommend some flavor of Lucene.

You have your option of the .NET flavor of Lucene.NET which Stackoverflow uses, Solr which is arguably easier to setup and get running than Lucene is, or the newest kid on the block which is ElasticSearch which aims to be schema free and infinitely scalable simply by dropping more instances in the cluster.

I have only used Solr myself, and it has a nice .NET client (SolrNet).

Comment: Solr is just a wrapper around Lucene's engine that brings a host of enhancements to Lucene and SolrNet is just an library to interface with Solr's REST service.  I cannot comment on the performance differences between Solr and stock Lucene or Lucene.net

Comment: Thanks Bryan, I downloaded Solr.NET files. I need to install & configure Lucene? Any guide on how to do all this stuff? Thanks

Comment: I followed this guide my first time.  Its meant for when you want to have two Solr indexes in a single instance but you can ignore that part: http://www.plaidpony.com/blog/post/2011/04/Multicore-SOLR-And-Tomcat-On-Windows-Server-2008-R2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

first index your database field that is important and very usable 
and for search better use **full text search** 
i try it and result is very different from when i dont use full text 
and better use select and join query in **stored proc** and call sp from your program

Comment: Any link configuring Full Text Searching and using it in ASP.NET? I am using currently EF to query my database. Thanks

Comment: there is no different between win app and web app to use full text, watch this link(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) or search more on google,if you dont success i can describe some helpful tip for start, and if you use EF you must add your **search sp** in your EF and call sp from there